# React toastify toast appears 4 times with every single call

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I recently started using react-toastify and everything worked fine until I noticed this odd behavior.

Here is my code:
`this.adderrorNotification('Error: Please try again!')`

```
adderrorNotification(message){ 
 toast.error(message, { 
   onClose: () => console.log('called when I close') 
 }); 
}
```

[image]

Up on toast onClose I see the log message 4 times.
and up on manual close click the toast re-appears 4 times.

Why is this happening ? Any help Thanks

Comment: Can you post your index file where toast is initialized?

Comment: Your comment just made me realize that I have initialized my toast in all my components which was causing the issue. (Sidebar, Navbar, Main component, Footer) which is making that render 4 times. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Remember to mark your question as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Cause: Initialized the toast in all my components which was causing the issue. (Sidebar, Navbar, Main component, Footer) which is making that render 4 times.

Solution: Removing the toast initialization in all components and initialized it in the index.js solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the good way for only 1 toast.

```
const test() {

    toast.dismiss(); //It will dismiss all toast before calling current one.
    
    toast.error("All fields are required")
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).